# I have got a problem in evaluation of a code

Tags: c#, .net

I have something like this

```
"This" + "  " + "is" + "  " + "the" + "  " + row["Message"].ToString() + "  " + "test" + "  " + "sms" + "  " + "to" + "  " + row["Name"].ToString();
```

which is constructed when the code executes

Comment: Ok.. now what is the problem ?

Comment: My question is why you have something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what your question is but might I recommend you use string.Format?

```
var message = string.Format("This is the {0} test sms to {1}", row["Message"], row["Name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an horrible string concatenation practice, not easily readable and a mess to understand and maintain, I suggest you to replace it with something like this using `string.Format` method:

```
var result = String.Format("This is the '{0}' test sms to '{1}'",
row["Message"].ToString(), row["Name"].ToString());
```